# Add "THIS has been renamed to THAT" for my own framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Let's say I have a framework, `A`, that I include in a lot of projects dynamically by adding `A.framework` file inside the projects.

Consider a scenario inside the code of framework `A` :

```
struct Foo {    
  static let `default` = Foo()    
}
```

Now I changed the name from `default` to `shared` :

```
struct Foo {    
  static let shared = Foo()    
}
```

Now, as we update the *Swift versions*, if some syntax changes, we sometimes get an error like

> 'NSLayoutAttribute' has been renamed to 'NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute'

wherein we tap the **fix** button inside that error and the name changes automatically.

I want to achieve the same when I make some *name change* or *function declaration change* inside my `A.framework` and roll it out to the apps using it. Is there a known way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve the same behaviour by using [@available](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) attribute.

```
struct Foo {

    @available(*, unavailable, renamed: "shared")
    static let defaults = Foo()

    static let shared = Foo()
}
```

It will give you an exact behaviour as shown here:

[image: Replace dialog]

---

**Note:**
You can do the same with functions as well, only thing is you have to have the same number of parameters.

```
struct Foo {

    @available(*, unavailable, renamed: "sharedFun(fName:lName:)")
    static func defaultFun(first: String, last: String) {}

    static func sharedFun(fName: String, lName: String) {}
}
```

[image: Replace dialog - Function]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how to do it for **function renaming** ?

Comment: @user121095 You can use the same attribute for function as well (Only thing is, you have to have the same number of input arguments): 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3hdT.png